# Why doesn't bezierPoints return unitless points?

Tags: r, grid-layout, bezier

I need to get the x- and y-coordinates of points along a Bezier curve in R. I thought this would work:

```
x <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)
y <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)
bg <- bezierGrob(x, y)
trace <- bezierPoints(bg)
```

But after running that trace$x and trace$y are a bunch of measurements in inches well outside the range of (0,1). The man page for bezierPoints says:

> Rather than drawing an Xspline (or Bezier curve), this function returns the points that would be used to draw the series of line segments for the Xspline.

Am I running into some grid weirdness? Or am I trying to use the wrong solution to this problem?

Comment: **Details** The points returned by this function will only be relevant for the drawing context in force when this function was called.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the bezier package, not grid, is the way to go. This works:

```
t <- seq(0, 1, length=100)
p <- matrix(c(0,0, 0,1, 1,1, 1,0), nrow=4, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
bp <- bezier(t=t, p=p)
```